# Inside exception handler, MessageBox() successfully returns IDOK but never shows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, exception

I'm using a self written exception class called windows_error that inherits from std::runtime_error, which I use to, well, properly handle unexpected errors from Windows API functions.

All the way on the bottom of the callstack, at the end of my WinMain function, I catch all windows_error exceptions that haven't been dealt with yet. I intend to handle them by display an error message right before the program terminates, like so:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE inst, HINSTANCE prev, wchar_t *cmdline, int winshow)
{
    // Initialize result to EXIT_FAILURE in case the program terminates due to
    // an exception.
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    try {
        result = sIRC()();
    }
    catch (windows_error &e) {
        e.basicHandler();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The basicHandler member function looks like this:

```
void windows_error::basicHandler() const
{
    std::wostringstream ss;

    ss << L"An unexpected error has occurred in a Windows function.\n\n" \
          L"Function " << m_api << L" was called by " << m_caller << L" in " << m_srcFile << L" at line " << m_srcLine << L". " \
          L"It returned error " << m_error << L":\n\n" << m_errorMessage;

#ifdef _CONSOLE
    std::wcout << L"\n" << ss.str();
#else
    auto result = MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, ss.str().c_str(), L"Windows error!", MB_ICONERROR);
    result = result; // I added this line so I can put a breakpoint in the debugger
#endif // _CONSOLE
}
```

When I started out with the program I'm working on, this worked beautifully. But now the program is starting to grow. While trying out new code I noticed the program seemed to terminate unexpectedly. By running it in the Visual C++ 2010 debugger, I noticed a windows_error exception being thrown. By stepping through the basicHandler function, I could see that the MessageBox function returns 1 (IDOK) without actually showing the message box...

What could cause this behavior?

I know my description is a little vague, but I have no idea what else to add... I couldn't find anything on MSDN that would suggest this behavior is even possible. There is no parent window handle I could pass to MessageBox, since they're all being destroyed during stack unwinding. I'm also positive that the stack is not unwound through a window procedure or any other Windows callback.

Any hint at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Could there be a stray quit message still in the queue?

Comment: Wow, THE Raymond Chen answering my question! I'm starstruck. :-) Hmm, during stack unwinding, my user_interface class' destructor does call DestroyWindow on the main window handle, which is handled by the window procedure with a PostQuitMessage. Is this not a good idea? I thought MessageBox creates its own message queue?

Comment: Functions do not have message queues. Threads have message queues. You are in the situation [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/08/10073040.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/05/20/8520129.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, it's clear to me now. Would you care to comment on the fix I came up with in my answer? It seems a bit clunky but it's the best I can come up with, with my admittedly limited understanding of the Windows API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond provided the hint I needed in his comment to my question. During stack unwinding the destructor of my user_interface class calls DestroyWindow on the window handle because it is still valid at that point. What I didn't know was that MessageBox interprets the resulting WM_QUIT message to close itself. I thought a message box had its own internal message queue?

I was able to fix my issue by modifying the destructor of my user_interface class.

It was:

```
if (_wnd)
    DestroyWindow(_wnd);
```

I changed it to:

```
if (_wnd) {
    DestroyWindow(_wnd);

    MSG msg = MSG();
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) {
        GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This works, but seems a little ugly. Any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: A message box has it's own message loop, but there is only one queue per thread.  You could launch a separate thread to display the message box, I suppose.

Comment: @Harry that seems a little overkill. :) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Um, if you do this in your destructor, then you're going to be throwing away messages even in the normal (no exceptions) case, which is not a good idea if somebody else wanted one of those messages. (E.g. the user performed typeahead that will go to some other window after yours has been destroyed.) And besides, it seems pointless to post a quit message and then immediately remove it.

Comment: The _wnd variable represents the main window in my programs UI. There is no other window for any typed ahead text to go to. In the normal, non-exception case, the _wnd isn't even a valid window handle anymore when the destructor is run. It will be set to NULL, as it has already been destroyed at the user's request. WM_QUIT will have already been processed normally. I see what you mean by it being pointless to post WM_QUIT in the exception case, but the window procedure is set up to call PostQuitMessage() when handling WM_DESTROY, and I'd like to keep it that way. Nothing of value will be lost.

Comment: @RaymondChen: according to MSDN, DestroyWindow flushes the thread's message queue anyway, so presumably the quit message will be the only thing left?  Or is there a subtlety here I'm missing?

Comment: You're assuming that the thread has no other windows. Even if you're eight, why bother posting a quit message if you're just going to hunt it down and throw it out? Why not just skip posting it in the first place?